# Does AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE trigger execute on multiple database instances?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a trigger created in the following manner in an Oracle database instance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_logon_on_database AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  -- some things that should be done on logon
END;
/
```

The Oracle server which I have my instance has multiple database instances running on it. I would want this trigger to run on a particular instance only.

Does `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` triggers run on every database instance on a given Oracle server?

Comment: Are you talking about multiple independent databases and instances, or multiple instances against the same database? The question implies they are related, but the [terminology is important](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1631683800346891854), and you might have separate environments. It would be fairly simple to verify whether your trigger fires on a particular session though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` trigger gets triggered every time someone logs on to the database, regardless which instance. So your trigger will get fired on every instance every time.

However, you can apply a condition to triggers so in your case you need something like this that the trigger will only get triggered on e.g. instance 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_logon_on_database AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
WHEN (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE') = 1)
BEGIN
  -- some things that should be done on logon
END;
/
```